# Laravel: Filtering results based on input from multiple checkboxes

Tags: laravel, filter

Struggling to figure out how to filter data in view using checkboxes. If only one location is selected, then it's straightforward. But what if multiple locations are selected? Is this a @foreach?

**My view**

```
<form method="post" action="filter">    
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="checkbox" name="locationfilter[]" value="Chicago">Chicago</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="locationfilter[]" value="New York">New York</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
```

**My controller**

```
$lofilter = implode(", ", $request->get('locationfilter'));
$mypostings = Postings::where('location', 'LIKE', '%'. $lofilter .'%')->get();
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter the locations in the view or the controller?

Comment: u want locations filtered with Or condition?

Comment: `whereIN` condition will work for comma separated match in Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereIn()` function to get values from given array,

```
users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

if you want to use `LIKE` operator try like this,

```
$checkbox = []; //assume this array as selected checkboxes
DB::query()
->Where(function ($query) use($checkbox) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($checkbox ); $i++){
          $query->orwhere('location', 'like',  '%' . $checkbox [$i] .'%');
    }  
})->get();
```

Comment: Sorry I'm beginner in laravel & eloquent but shouldn't be  $query->where  instead of  $query->orwhere?

Comment: read this one, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses

Comment: @CasperSL - Thank you.

Comment: @CasperSL
I finally get it, I know I'm slow but I'm 50 years old :) !
You have used orwhere because you will have a lot's of "wheres" due to the for cycle and you have to get all the incidences :)
Thank you again!